# Did the Thai monk Bhikkhu Buddhadasa teach Anapansati incorrectly?

Tags: papanca

I read the following comment on the internet:

> *Buddhadasa, his health
>   failed him revealed he had no attainment in "Anapanasati", though
>   written [550 pages](http://dhammatalks.net/Books3/Buddhadasa_Bhikkhu-Anapanasati.pdf) on it. He was just a Bhikkhu-scholar groomed by
>   Theosophical Society, his teaching contained poison.*

Is there any evidence Buddhadasa was groomed by the Theosophical Society? Also, what evidence exists the health of Buddhadasa failed him to prevent Anapanasati? When he was in his final years, I saw he would sit very still crossed legged (although with back supported by chair) for up to 3 hours giving a talk. There was no visible evidence to most people in the audience he had physical discomfort (unlike the audience, who often sat in physical discomfort for at least 2 hours). In fact, at a time when it was said his passing was imminent, I saw him lose often consciousness when giving a (live translated) lecture when the translator would speak; then he would be woken up; and continue the talk exactly at the point he previously stopped. Most importantly, what errors did Buddhasasa make in his teachings about Anapanasati?

Comment: I don't know Bikkhu Buddhadhasa, but I've met several monks and laypeople who can stand still in lotus posture for much more than 3 hours, I believe that by itself is a feat but not a mark of some kind of attainment.

Comment: I don't know anyone without a calm body that can sit still for 3 hours. Regardless, the question is not about "attainment". It is about basic anapanasati. One thing I am confident about is you cannot sit still for 3 hours.

Comment: The quote you mention specifically says "... had no attainment in Anapanasati". I don't understand how you can be confident of someone else's practice.

Comment: Well, you made a comment elsewhere referring to Mahayana Masters. How could you be confident in them? Buddhadasa taught Anapanasati correctly because it accords with the Dhamma.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

About anapanasati, there are many modern teachers talking about this but I have only read Buddhadasa comment extensively on the key phrase found in the sutta, namely: "*He trains himself*".

The same as Buddhadasa, the suttas define the term "training" to refer to the Threefold Training, as follows:

> ***There are these three trainings. Which three? The training in heightened virtue, the training in heightened mind, the training in
>   heightened discernment.***
>
> ***AN 3.88 Sikkha Sutta: Training***

This below from his [550 pages](http://dhammatalks.net/Books3/Buddhadasa_Bhikkhu-Anapanasati.pdf) is merely one point providing evidence to a hypothesis that Buddhadasa taught anapanasati correctly and every one else taught anapanasati incorrectly.

> [image]

---

---

Related to the point above, the Buddha said he teaches about suffering & the cessation of suffering (MN 22). Suffering is created by the mind rather than by the body. Since the phrase: "*He trains himself*" must include insight into suffering & the ending of suffering, that is, the four noble truths, I have also only read Buddhadasa teach this from step 3, as follows:

> [image]

This above from his [550 pages](http://dhammatalks.net/Books3/Buddhadasa_Bhikkhu-Anapanasati.pdf) is merely a 2nd point providing evidence to a hypothesis that Buddhadasa taught anapanasati correctly and every one else taught anapanasati incorrectly.

---

---

Below from his [550 pages](http://dhammatalks.net/Books3/Buddhadasa_Bhikkhu-Anapanasati.pdf) is a 3rd point providing evidence to a hypothesis that Buddhadasa taught anapanasati correctly and every one else taught anapanasati incorrectly. I have never read the following explanation by any other teacher; yet the explanation below accords with the principles in the suttas about feeling & perception.

[image]

Buddhadasa explains this more clearly in his later work, below:

> *EXPERIENCING THE MIND-CONDITIONER*
>
> *Now we come to step seven: "experiencing the mind­-conditioner (cittasankhara-patisamvedi)." If we have completed step six
>   successfully, then we know all about the feelings of piti and sukha.
>   What does the arising of piti do to the citta? What does the arising
>   of sukha do to the citta? What kind of thoughts does piti condition?
>   What kind of thoughts does sukha condition? We have noted and
>   scrutinized these effects since steps five and six. Once we come to
>   step seven, it is easy to realize that, "Oh, piti and sukha are
>   mind-conditioners." These vedana are mind-conditioners in the same way
>   that the breath is the body-conditioner. The method of study and
>   observation is the same as in step three. (107)*
>
> *We have observed that piti is coarse and excited, whereas sukha is fine and peaceful. Thus, when piti conditions or brews up a thought,
>   the thought is coarse. On the other hand, when sukha brews up a
>   thought, it is calm and tranquil. This is how we realize that the
>   vedana condition thoughts. Then we realize that the feelings condition
>   both coarse thoughts and subtle thoughts. We call this activity
>   "conditioning the mind."    (108)*
>
> *When piti is strong, it causes trembling in the body. And if it is very strong the body might even dance or bounce with joy. This
>   feel­ing is coarse and powerful. On the other hand, sukha is calming,
>   soothing, and relaxing. We learn that their characteristics are very
>   different. When piti dominates the mind, it is impossible to think
>   subtle thoughts. We feel a tingling all over; it makes the hair stand
>   up all over our bodies. So we need to be able to control piti. Sukha,
>   however, has advantages. It leads to tranquil, refined states. It can
>   cause subtle, profound, and refined thoughts. It is as if these two
>   feelings are opponents or foes. But that does not matter, for we know
>   how to regulate them. We are able to control them by training
>   according to the method we are now practicing. Just this much is to
>   understand the citta-sankhara reasonably well already.*
>
> *In the end, we will realize that the feelings (e.g., piti and sukha) are mind-conditioners. When piti conditions it, the citta is coarse
>   and its thoughts are coarse, both the mind and the thoughts are
>   coarse. When sukha conditions or supports it, the citta is subtle and
>   tranquil, and its thoughts are subtle and tranquil. Both feelings
>   condition the mind, but from different angles. The vedana are
>   conditioners of the citta, thus they get the name "mind-conditioner
>   (citta-sankhara)." (112)*
>
> [*Unveiling the Secrets of Life: a Manual for Serious Beginners*](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm)

Answer (score 1):

According to your question:

> Did the Thai monk Bhikkhu Buddhadasa teach Anapansati incorrectly?

**Buddhadasa's ānāpānassati** is the translation version of [paṭisambhidāmagga](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=31&A=4070&w=%CD%D2%B9%D2%BB%D2%B9), [visuddhimagga](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf), and ānāpānassati's [commentary](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=5&A=9640&h=sikkh%C4%81). **He copied all of them from the commentary.**

So, for the anti-abhidhammist, it is incorrect. But for the abhidhammist it is correct.

Comment: This answer is obviously wrong because Buddhadada obviously did not copy "all" of it.

Comment: Obviously, the conclusion of the original  is a copy. Or you can give me the difference place of them? Everyone can read in my link to prove what I have written above.

Comment: I have never read Buddhadasa's 550 pages. I tried to read it once but found it too long with too much unnecessary things. The book translated in 1988 is sufficient and better. https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm   However, the parts highlighted in my answer are correct according to the suttas.  For the anti-abhidhammist, the parts i highlighted are correct

Comment: You can compare it with the link I put above.

Comment: I do not need to compare it. Obviously, the 550 page book is based on paṭisambhidāmagga, visuddhimagga, and ānāpānassati's commentary. However, this does not mean it is all incorrect.

Comment: You never read from the other teacher, can't prove whether it is incorrect or correct as well.

Comment: Its correct according to the suttas.

Comment: I can quote the correct words  and ignore the incorrect words of  the thieve to admired him as a guiltless person as well. Because I have biases. But if I want really prove the evidence I must try to understand them all,  thieve,  plaintiff witnessed, and defendant. This is how people should do before judge something. That's the reason why I memorize them in pāli before judge them.

Comment: You are welcome to quote whatever you wish but this is irrelevant to the question. The question is about the correct teaching of anapanasati.

Comment: Can't you read your own question?

Comment: I can read the question. You did not answer the question.